# Happstack: Empty Cookies

Tags: haskell, cookies, web, happstack

I am trying to access the `rqCookies` attribute of a `Request` in Happstack Server, however I continue to get an empty list, when there are cookies that are in the request headers.

I have also tried to use the `readCookieValue` function, but this cannot find *any* of the cookies.

Why is this happening?

The server is being run on Ubuntu 14.04.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cookies contained commas, and were not parsed correctly.